# php, error of getting json data

Tags: php, json, get

I have a webapp on my local server wich is currently using PHP 5.3.8. My webapp works perfect.
Now I am testing the same code on our public host that uses PHP 5.3.3-7 + squeeze9 (no idea of what is squeeze).

The point here is that a simple get of some JSON data in the url doesn't work on the host.

I am using this:

```
http://webs.myapp.com/print.php?data=[%22O20130718ASDAS460600442%22]
```

At my local server I am able to get the info in data like this:

```
$info = json_decode($_GET['data']);   
$acompanantes = $info[0];
```

but I am not able to do the same on the other server. I know that if I update the host server php's to the 5.3.8 99% it will work, but I am afraid that the other things hosted there will stop working as soon as I update it.

Any idea on how should I try to get the data ?? What am I doing wrong ??

Thanks in advance.

PS: both servers use JSON version 1.2.1.

Comment: What does `json_last_error()` return? Btw squeeze is a debian version.

Comment: How can a URL not work? It returns a "Not Found" error?

Comment: "4" is a valid answer to that question ?? 

I did:

$info = json_decode($_GET['datos']);       
echo json_last_error();

Comment: Yes, and it's `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`. Have a look at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Álvaro, url works fine, but retrieving the json data doesnt

Comment: Then I guess that "the URL doesn't work" means "the output contains a PHP error message". Have you had a look at your script's output?

Comment: Alvaro, the url I posted is not the real one that uses the script, its just an example

Comment: @AlbertPrats - Do you need help on how to open the URL in your browser and inspect its output?

Comment: The GET variable "data" in your URLs query string contains the character "[". Maybe you should check that your server is not blocking it as an invalid character.